# How to update all of the values of a table using merge into statement

Tags: sql, oracle

How to update all the values from source table to destination table using `merge into` statement?

What I am trying to do is something like:

```
merge into src_table
using (select * from dest) dest_table
on (<some_condition>)
when matched then update set src_table.* = dest_table.*
where <condition>
```

I didn't find anything related to this on Google. I know one can achieve this using `execute immediate` style statement but I am looking for a better way.

Comment: You would have to specify each column you want to update explicitly, except those columns used in the `on` clause - they cannot be updated.

Comment: so why you dont use alter rename ?

Answer (score 1):

### you can do it with pl/sql

```
for src in ( select * from B ) loop
  update A set ROW = src where A.id = src.id; 
end loop;
```

### or you can use alter table;

```
alter table your_table
rename to
   your_new_table;
```